# What is the current convergence criterion of glmnet?

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I have attempted to reproduce the results of glmnet with the convergence criterion described in equation 1 and 2 or in the vignette in Appendix 0 on page 34: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnet.pdf

[equation1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idahn.gif)
[equation2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idahn.gif)

Considering that each observation has a weight of 1, this gives me:

```
delta[i]=crossprod(X[, i], X[, i])* (beta_last[i] - beta_new[i])**2
```

Then I check if max(delta)>=eps, as described in the vignette

Using this criterion, I do not get the same number of iterations as the glmnet results (often a lag of one or two iterations), leading me to believe that it is out of date. By the way, it seems that the convergence criterion of the glmnet algorithm in the Gaussian case has changed regularly in the last few years.

Do you know what criterion is used to determine the convergence of the algorithm ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`glmnet` rescales the weights to sum to 1 before starting the fit, so you're missing a 1/n factor in the definition of delta[i]. But with that fix, this is the criterion used in the current version of `glmnet` (4.1-3) and also in version 4.1-2. Keep in mind, there are may be other differences like active set/strong set that you may not be using in exactly the same way as `glmnet` does, which can also affect the number of coordinate descents you realize.